# How to replicate Excel COUNTIFS in Pandas with non-equal conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried search SO and other places, but every answer seems to provide a groupby() answer, which I don't believe applies to my situation.

Scenario: A site needs to be inspected every 3 calendar months (i.e. if inspected anytime in January, it needs to be inspected again by April 30). For each inspection, site and date, I want a count of subsequent inspections performed in that 3 calendar month window.

Below is expected output. The COUNTIF formula just shows the formula created to achieve the count column in Excel.

| site | date | count | COUNTIF formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 2 | =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A2,$B$2:$B$10,">"&B2,$B$2:$B$10,"<="&EOMONTH(B2,3)) |
| 1 | 2/15/2021 | 1 | =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A3,$B$2:$B$10,">"&B3,$B$2:$B$10,"<="&EOMONTH(B3,3)) |
| 1 | 4/25/2021 | 0 | =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A4,$B$2:$B$10,">"&B4,$B$2:$B$10,"<="&EOMONTH(B4,3)) |
| 1 | 12/1/2021 | 0 | =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A5,$B$2:$B$10,">"&B5,$B$2:$B$10,"<="&EOMONTH(B5,3)) |
| 2 | 1/1/2021 | 1 | =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A6,$B$2:$B$10,">"&B6,$B$2:$B$10,"<="&EOMONTH(B6,3)) |
| 2 | 3/25/2021 | 0 | =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A7,$B$2:$B$10,">"&B7,$B$2:$B$10,"<="&EOMONTH(B7,3)) |
| 3 | 5/1/2021 | 0 | =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A8,$B$2:$B$10,">"&B8,$B$2:$B$10,"<="&EOMONTH(B8,3)) |
| 3 | 11/1/2021 | 1 | =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A9,$B$2:$B$10,">"&B9,$B$2:$B$10,"<="&EOMONTH(B9,3)) |
| 3 | 12/1/2021 | 0 | =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A10,$B$2:$B$10,">"&B10,$B$2:$B$10,"<="&EOMONTH(B10,3)) |

Comment: is your data sorted? not touched excel for a hot minute, but I assume you want to check  each site and unique date against the future dates right?

Comment: I do have it sorted by site, then date